# How to save offline messages in mosquitto broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have a `raspberry pi` where I have installed mosquitto. I am using pub and sub to send and receive messages between pi and my ubuntu machine. I have made a file `iot.conf` and placed it in `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/iot.conf`. Following is the content of the file:

`connection CONIOT
log_type all
address 192.168.1.154:8883
remote_clientid sensor1
bridge_cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
try_private false
cleansession true
start_type automatic
bridge_insecure false
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_tls_version tlsv1
notifications false`

`topic # out 0 sensor/sensor1 sensor/sensor1
topic # in 0 sensor/sensor1 sensor/sensor1`

The ip address is the ip address of my raspberry pi. On the raspberry pi I have made a small python script which publish the sensor 1 data. On my ubuntu machine I can receive the data by using the below command:

```
mosquitto_sub -t sensor/sensor1 -h 192.168.1.154
```

In the above command I have given the topic and the host ip address. So this way I am able to receive all the message from pi. But I want to test if the pi goes offline (no wifi/lan) then does the messages are stored locally on the pi, and when it come back online, can I receive all the messages.

I tested this with above configuration but was not able to receive offline messages. I have made the `cleansession` true as per descibed [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm126048118493120).

Can anyone please point me where I am doing mistake. I want mosquitto to save offline message when the pi is not connected to wifi/lan. How can I test this.?

Here is the content of the /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf file:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `cleansession` set to  true you will not get any queued message because it instructs the broker to discard any queued messages.

You need to set `cleansession` to false and ensure you are using the a fixed clientid for both the pi broker and the mosquitto_sub client if you want the broker on your ubuntu machine to queue messages for the pi, then to forward those to the client.

Comment: HI. Thanks for the information. I didnt get the part where you mentioned using fixed clientid. Can you explain it again. On the ubuntu side, I am normally using `mosquitto_sub` command with -t and -h for topic and hostname. Do I need to add client with `mosquitto_sub` command, and also the client you are referring, is it sensor1 as I have mentioned `remote_clientid sensor1` in my iot.conf file. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear from your question which way data is flowing. But messages are queued a given broker on a per client basis so clientids need to be fixed for each client (The broker is it's self a client when bridging) if you want to recover messages missed by that particular client.

Comment: Data is flowing from pi to ubuntu. I have connected a sensor in pi. I am using `paho-mqtt` python library to publish messages. On the ubuntu machine I am receiving it using mosquitto_sub. I have done the configuration (as described in question) and saved it in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/ to be used by mosquitto. This is all my setup

Comment: I did the changes you mentioned. I made cleansession to false and then on the ubuntu machine I used the command mosquitto_sub and also included client name using -i sensor1 but I didnt received the message when the device lost the connection.

Comment: Then we would need to see the config for the broker on the pi as well. And what QOS the messages are being published at. Also your bridge is running at QOS 0 so there is no guarantee that any messages will be queued when the bridge is down

Comment: I have added the content of the `mosquitto.conf` file. I didnt get the QOS as I have not set this in iot.conf file. How can I check it or set it. Thanks

Comment: Yes you have, the 0 in the `topic` line is the QOS for the bridge

Comment: Okay and thank you. I just want to confirm about the cleansession. I think setting clean session to false with QOS 1/2 will only deliver the offline messages as described [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mqtt-7.html). Also which QOS 1 or 2 I should set to get offline messages.

Comment: I am able to get the offline messages but only for 20 to 30 secs after this I am not getting any offline message. Do you have any idea about this. Is there any limit or something which we can increase.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue with the help of hardilb. This is what I did to get the offline messages:

1. Set cleansession to false
2. Fixed client id
3. used QOS 1.

Thanks.